# Maximum data size for table per row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

According to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/about/)

> Maximum Columns per Table 250 - 1600 depending on column types

Ok, but if have less than 250 columns, but several they contains really big data, many text type columns and many array type columns (with many elements), then there is any limit?

Question is: there is any size limit for per row? (sum of all columns content).

Comment: the oversized columns will go to TOAST, the limit of one cell is 1GB if I'm not mistaken

Comment: the maximum number of columns is defined by the block size (they all should fit one block) - I did not try, but I suppose If you compile postgres to have a bigger page, you will be able to store more columns (like 16 KB would allow 500-3200 and so on)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html